# AngularJS : subview's controller never called

Tags: angularjs, controller

My controller `listMembersController` is never called and I don't understand why.

What my app have to do :

- I go to http://localhost:3000/#/lobby
- In List Member section : I get users.

**lobby.html**

```
<h1>Lobby</h1> 
<div ng-include src="'partials/lobby/lobby-quickFight.html'">
</div> <div ng-include src="'partials/lobby/lobby-chatMessenger.html'"></div>
<div ng-include src="'partials/lobby/lobby-listMembers.html'"></div>
```

**lobby-listMembers.html**

```
<div id="container-list-members" class="col-md-4" ng-controller="listMembersController">
<div class="lobby-container">
    <h1>List members!</h1>
    <p> {{ users }}</p>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users">
        <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
    </li>
</div>
```

**LobbyController.js**

```
app.controller('lobbyController', function($rootScope, $scope) {
    $rootScope.title = "Lobby";
    console.log('I'm in lobbyController');
});
```

This log appear. Problem is in the next controller:

**ListMembersController.js**

```
app.controller('listMembersController', function($rootScope, $scope, JSFAPI) {
    $scope.users = function() {
        console.log('I'm in a listMembersController');
        JSFAPI.getUsers(); //Get users in JSON format thanks to nodejs server
    };

});
```

First this log doesn't appear so I think this function is never called.

**client.js**

```
var app = angular.module('jsfighterclient', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
   $stateProvider
    .state("lobby", {
        url: "/lobby",
        templateUrl: "partials/lobby.html",
           controller: "lobbyController",
        data: {
            loginRequired: false
        }
    });
});
```

I'm new in the angularJS community so apologies if this is easy. I try to search answers before post here but I've difficulty to find words for my problem.

I think the import point in my case is that my view is composed with other views and it's this subview which do an action.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ng-repeater is looking for 'users' to be an Object/Array.

Try this:

```
app.controller('listMembersController', function($rootScope, $scope, JSFAPI) {

    console.log("I'm in a listMembersController");    

    $scope.users = JSFAPI.getUsers(); //Get users in JSON format thanks to nodejs server
});
```

Comment: Thanks it's work. But why I can't set a callback function to $scope.users ? 
I see it in lots of example !

You say that ng-repeater is looking for an Object/Array so it can't use a json ?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean by adding a callback function to $scope.users, but typically you would put the callback function on your service call(if $http call), like so:
`JSFAPI.getUsers().then(function (rslt) { 
    console.log("callback");
    $scope.users = rslt; 
});`

Comment: Ok ! Thanks ! I think, I don't fully understand. I'm new on this technology. I'll read more tutorial about this.